# Eclipse : How to terminate all applications at once?

Tags: java, eclipse

is there some way to terminate all (Java) applications launched with Eclipse at once?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Open the debug view, select all, and click the big red box (or right-click and select "Terminate").

Comment: or Teminate/Discomnect All

Comment: Oh yes, didn't think debug view. Thanks =)

Comment: I forgot to put `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` on a `JFrame`. It took a stunning 2 minutes to close all of the 200 instances I had made so far, even with this method.