# in Eclipse is there a shortcut to terminate and remove all tasks at once?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse every time we want to remove the terminated/ interrupted tasks we have to first select them, then right click and select terminate and remove. Is there a shorter way to do this? 
PS. needless to mention, I am looking for a shorter way than what I already know in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644040/eclipse-how-to-terminate-all-applications-at-once)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just found delete key works from another thread and for more than just debugging java! Why it's not on the menu or on the Keys preferences beats me?

Answer (score 0):

I found it, clicking on those gray cross signs on the top-right corner will do the job

Comment: That is `Remove all terminated launched` so it does not really do what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> with the Debug window focused and then press <kbd>Delete</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.