# Terminate Keyboard Shortcut for Mulesoft Anypoint Studio

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mule, anypoint-studio

It gets really annoying to have to open the console everytime I want to stop debugging. The preferences map Ctrl+F2 to terminate, but this shortcut doesn't seem to do anything. I've tried remapping it but no luck, any ideas?

UPDATE - Must be an issue with Eclipse. I found this similar question which doesn't mention a solution. You would think there would be some way to bind a shortcut to the terminate command given how often it's used.

[Eclipse Terminate Keyboard Shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803365/eclipse-terminate-keyboard-shortcut)

Answer (score 1):

If your purpose is only: *how to stop the project (debugging) without opening the Console*, then you can right click on the *Canvas* and select: *stop project [project name]*

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with that menu though. It's a little faster but takes about as long as clicking the red terminate button. I saw in another post that you can use alt to bring up the menus in Eclipse, but there's no terminate command in the menus in Anypoint. Frustrating.